# How to increase accuracy for CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, python

I have built one CNN model and applied it to chest-xray Covid 19 pneumonia dataset. I am getting the classification report as follows:

[image]

I am surprised to see that it is giving an excellent result on minority class but relatively poor on **class 1**. Can anybody help me tune my model so that I can build a more robust model?

CNN code

```
def architecture (_img_dims ):
    
    inputs = Input(shape=(_img_dims, _img_dims, 3))

    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x)

    
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = SeparableConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x)

    
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.7)(x)
    x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.3)(x)

    # Output layer
    output = Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(x)
    
    return inputs, output
```

**INFO ABOUT CLASSES**

- Class 0:  COVID
- Class 1:  Normal
- Class 2:  Pneumonia

Image SAMPLE

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have also used Data-Augmentation. Still the result is same

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=10,
        zoom_range=0.4,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.01
        )
```

**Edit**

I am trying to increase, the number of class-level 1 images i.e Normal Images by using AC-GAN. Code is taken from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-an-auxiliary-classifier-gan-ac-gan-from-scratch-with-keras/)

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import asarray
from numpy.random import randn
from keras.models import load_model
from matplotlib import pyplot
 
# generate points in latent space as input for the generator
def generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_samples, n_class):
    # generate points in the latent space
    x_input = randn(latent_dim * n_samples)
    # reshape into a batch of inputs for the network
    z_input = x_input.reshape(n_samples, latent_dim)
    # generate labels
    labels = asarray([n_class for _ in range(n_samples)])
    return [z_input, labels]
 
# create and save a plot of generated images
def save_plot(examples, n_examples):
    # plot images
    for i in range(n_examples):
        # define subplot
        pyplot.subplot(sqrt(n_examples), sqrt(n_examples), 1 + i)
        # turn off axis
        pyplot.axis('off')
        # plot raw pixel data
        pyplot.imshow(examples[i, :, :, 0], cmap='gray_r')
    pyplot.show()
 
# load model
model = load_model('../input/model111/Xception.h5')
latent_dim = 224
n_examples = 100 # must be a square
n_class = 1 # Normal
# generate images
latent_points, labels = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_examples, n_class)
# generate images
X  = model.predict([latent_points, labels])
# scale from [-1,1] to [0,1]
X = (X + 1) / 2.0
# plot the result
save_plot(X, n_examples)
```

But I am getting error as

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>]
```

Comment: could you describe more in details what the class represent? (maybe add a couple of images as well). There can be many reasons why class 0 is detected better than class 1 even with less examples, e.g. if class 0 were bananas, class 1 oranges and class 2 mandarins, the color would suffice to get that class perfectly with few examples. So the CNN code is kinda useless here, more important is to inspect the data.

Comment: Hello @EdoardoGuerriero , I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks @Bazzz for your suggestions